# Share selected text in listView item

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a ListView with text items.

How do I make Share (in the charms bar) available when a given item is selected, and then pass that selected item into the Share contract?

I know how to share, but I don't know how to get the selected text item.

Comment: Do you want the share to actually open when one is selected? Or just be available for the user to select (so that if they have an item selected and hit the Share Charm, then the contents will be available to share)?

Comment: in the share event handler, you can use `SelectedItem`, `SelectedItems` or `SelectedIndex` property of the ListView to get selected item and its text.

Comment: Yes, i can get all text. but i want to get only selected by user text.

Comment: Show your listview selectedchanged event ..

Comment: @matzone I have no selectionChanged event. I don't need to select any item. Only selected text by user in this item. For example I want to make share like in Mail client in Windows8. If user select some text in letter than Share option available. And user share only selected text.

Comment: how about binding [TextBlock.SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx) property to your viewmodel (list view item) twoway and that way you can get selected text as `SelectedItem.SelectedText`?

Comment: @Sushil Yes, i think its a good idea. If you have free time, may be you can show simple code example?

Answer (score 0):

To get Selected Listview item text

```
String s = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).text
```

Comment: User can't select any item. SelectionMode = None.

Comment: Error is: Object does not contain a defenition for Text!